# Typo in memcache.php 3.0.6, what version of memcache to use?

Tags: php, memcached

I've downloaded `memcache.php` version 3.0.6 [from there](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache) and out of the box (after defining the memcache server with `$MEMCACHE_SERVERS[] = 'localhost:11211';`) I got the following error:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant values - assumed 'values' in memcache_3.0.6.php on line 61
```

Relevant code block:

```
   function get_host_port_from_server($server){
            $values = explode(':', $server);
            if (($values[0] == 'unix') && (!is_numeric( $values[1]))) {
                    return array($server, 0);
            }
        else {
                    return values;   // lines 61 -> $ missing
            }
    }
```

After correcting that I realized [the bug had already been raised](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=59887). Since [3.0.6 was released 10 months ago](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcache), I'm surprised that typo hasn't been fixed yet, and I'm wondering whether it's because people mostly use other versions. By extrapolating I would like to ask the following question:

**Q: What version of memcache.php, memcached, and php-memcache do you use?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [memcached](http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached) **extension**. It is a wrapper for [libmemcached](http://libmemcached.org) and active developed